# AlivePDF not writing out text using addText(). Nothign I'm trying is working. What am I missing?

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, pdf-generation, alivepdf

No matter what I try I can't write anything to a PDF that can be seen, although the text is there when viewing the resultant PDF in Notepad.  What am I not doing?   Here's a code snippet.  the variable tf is a TextField defined in the class.  This works in the SWF, just not with PDF.

```
    private function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        tf.text = "Hey, you clicked the button!";

        myPDF = new PDF(Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.INCHES, Size.A4);
        myPDF.setDisplayMode(Display.FULL_PAGE, Layout.SINGLE_PAGE)
        myPDF.addPage();
        myPDF.addText(tf.text, 20, 20 );

        var filename:String = "Test-file.pdf";
        var f:FileStream = new FileStream();
        var file:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(filename);
        f.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        var bytes:ByteArray = myPDF.save(Method.LOCAL);
        f.writeBytes(bytes);
        f.close();
    }
```

Comment: ved.  Changed Unit.INCHES to Unit.MM and it worked.  Not sure what the issue was.

Comment: Maybe the units affect the 20 in addText then 20 inches is way out of page than 20mm:)